# Bootstrap carousal is not working in production app but works in local

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have created an app with react and boostrap there i used bootstrap 4 carousal. Everything is working perfectly in local.
after deployment Bootstrap carousal animation and clicking on indicators stopped working. I created production build using `npm run build`, deployed in ec2 instance and  serving the website using pm2 , nginx.

Why is it not working after deployment.

Comment: go to developer tools, network tab... do you see any 404s ?

Comment: @AkberIqbal No 404 on network tab